# Button height percentage not changing

Tags: css

I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Friends </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            html {
                background-image: url(images/RegisterAndLoginBackground.jpg);
            }
            body {
                margin: 0px;
            }
            h1 {
                margin-top: 3%;
                margin-bottom: 4%;
            }
            ul {
                list-style-type: none;
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
                background-color: #03cafc;
            }
            #Home, #AddFriends {
                float: left;
            }
            li a {
                display: block;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 18px 16px;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
            li a:hover {
                background-color: #058db0;
            }
            #AddFriend, #RequestsOne, #RequestsTwo {
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                width: 14%;
                height: 30%;
                margin-top: 15px;
                margin-bottom: 15px;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                background-color: #03cafc;
            }
            input {
                width: 60%;
                height: 15%;
            }
            #AddFriendButton {
                margin-top: 6%;
                border-style: solid;
                background-color: #8ae7ff;
                border-color: #004354;
                width: 50%;
                height: 100%;
                font-size: 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>
            <div id = "NavBar">
                <ul id>
                    <li id = "Home"> <a href = "LoggedIn.html"> Home </a> </li>
                    <li id = "AddFriends"> <a href = "Friends.html"> Friends </a> </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id = "AddFriend">
                <h1> Add Friend </h1>
                <label for = "Username"> Username: </label>
                <input type = "text" id = "Username">
                <button id = "AddFriendButton"> Add Friend </button>
            </div>
            <div id = "RequestsOne"> 
                <h1> Requests Received </h1>
                <ul id = "RequestsReceived">
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id = "RequestsTwo">
                <h1> Requests Sent </h1>
                <ul id = "RequestsSent">
                    
                </ul>
           </div>
        </main> //Some more code
```

My problem is that AddFriendButton height does not work. I know the parent height has to be defined, which I believe I did. On another page, it worked. I'm not really sure, this is my first time making a large website. I know it will work if I use pixels instead. It will also get larger if I change the font size, but why won't height percentage work?

Answer (score 1):

The containing block for `#AddFriendButton` is `#AddFriend`

It is a percentage of its height.

The height of `#AddFriend` is 30%.

Again, it is a percentage of the height of the block containing it.

The containing block for `#AddFriend` is `main`

But `main` has no height.

Therefore, browsers cannot calculate heights by percentages.

Try to give specific height to `main`.